# Expectation of two independent stochasts

Tags: probability

Consider the stochasts $X$ and $Y$ that are both independent and take with the same probability the values $1$ or $-1$. I have to calculate the expected value $E[(X+Y)e^{-X}]$ Because of the linearity of the expected value, it follows that $E[(X+Y)e^{-X}]=E[Xe^{-X}]+E[Ye^{-X}]$.

This is where I am stuck. Firstly I do not know what the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is. It can't be a Bernoulli variable since in that case $E[X]=p=1/2$, but here it is clearly $E[X]=0$. Secondly, I assume $E[Xe^{-X}]\neq E[X]E[e^{=X}]=0$. Is that a good assumption?

My second question handles with the variable $Z=XY$. I suppose $X$ and $Z$ are independent since $Cov(X,Z)=Cov(X,XY)=Cov(X,X)*Cov(X,Y)=Var(X)*0=0$ and hence independent. Is this proof correct?

Comment: $X$ and $XY$ are independent in this case, but not in general even when $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  Zero covariance does not imply independence.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I made a typo, it should have been $E[e^{-X}]$ and not $E[e^{-x}]$. So I suppose I can't just take out the $e^{-X}$ out of the expectation.